# Select rows before a filtered row using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm working on a study where we used a camera placed inside a nest box to determine when our study species laid its first egg. Some of the cameras weren't super reliable, and I'd like to see if there were continuous photos before the date where the first egg was laid. This way I can no for sure that this is the first egg date. There are >165,000 photos and >200 nests, so I grouped by nest box ID, filtered the rows down to those that have at least 1 egg, and then used the slice function to select the first row with data. Here's a reproducible example:

```
example <- structure(list(boxID = c("CA10", "CA10", "CA10", "CA10", "CA10", 
    "CA10", "CA10", "CA10", "CA10", "CA10", "CA10", "CA10", "CA10", 
    "CA10", "CA10"), visitType = c("Image", "Image", "Image", "Image", 
    "Image", "Image", "Image", "Image", "Image", "Image", "Image", 
    "Image", "Image", "Image", "Image"), day = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 
    26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L), month = c("MAR", 
    "MAR", "MAR", "MAR", "MAR", "MAR", "MAR", "MAR", "MAR", "MAR", 
    "MAR", "MAR", "MAR", "MAR", "MAR"), year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018), timeChecked = c("02:59", "09:06", "15:13", "02:59", "09:07", 
    "15:14", "02:59", "09:07", "15:13", "02:58", "09:06", "15:12", 
    "02:58", "09:06", "15:12"), species = c("Empty", "Empty", "Empty", 
    "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "American Kestrel", 
    "Empty", "American Kestrel", "American Kestrel", "American Kestrel", 
    "American Kestrel", "American Kestrel"), sexAdult = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Female", NA, "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    NA, NA), numEggs = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), numNestlings = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), date = structure(c(17615, 
    17615, 17615, 17616, 17616, 17616, 17617, 17617, 17617, 17618, 
    17618, 17618, 17619, 17619, 17619), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), .Names = c("boxID", 
    "visitType", "day", "month", "year", "timeChecked", "species", 
    "sexAdult", "numEggs", "numNestlings", "date"))
```

Here's the code I have to find the first row that has at least 1 egg:

```
example %>%
      mutate_at(vars(numEggs, numNestlings), na_if, 'unknown') %>% # remove unknowns and other values that should be NA
      select(boxID, date, numEggs, visitType) %>%
      group_by(boxID) %>%
      filter(numEggs > 0) %>%
      slice(1)
```

I'd like to look at the 5 or 10 rows before this first row with an egg to make sure there was continuous data up to this point in time. Is there a way to do this row indexing with slice or some other dplyr function?

Comment: what is the definition of 'having continuous data up to certain point'? 5 or 10 rows before certain point could be from many days/weeks/months ago which would and should indicate bad data for your purpose.

Comment: @Shree that's what I'm looking to see - are there photos everyday or mulitple times per day before the first egg is laid? Or was the last photos weeks ago because the camera wasn't working

Comment: I get that, but what is the exact definition/threshold that separates good from the bad? Or do you do you just want to look at the previous 5/10 rows?

Comment: @Shree just interested in filtering out that first egg row, and a few rows before that

Comment: Okay, got it! makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. `match` returns the position of first `numEggs > 0` and then we simply get additional `n_previous` rows from that position. We use `max(1, ...)` so that we don't get error if position of first `numEggs > 0` `<` `n_previous` .

```
n_previous <- 5

example %>%
  mutate_at(vars(numEggs, numNestlings), na_if, 'unknown') %>% 
  select(boxID, date, numEggs, visitType) %>%
  group_by(boxID) %>%
  slice(max(1, match(TRUE, numEggs > 0) - n_previous):match(TRUE, numEggs > 0))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   boxID [1]
  boxID date       numEggs visitType
  <chr> <date>     <chr>   <chr>    
1 CA10  2018-03-26 <NA>    Image    
2 CA10  2018-03-27 <NA>    Image    
3 CA10  2018-03-27 <NA>    Image    
4 CA10  2018-03-27 <NA>    Image    
5 CA10  2018-03-28 <NA>    Image    
6 CA10  2018-03-28 1       Image
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a way based on slicing according to the position of the first non missing value of `numEggs`. You can modify the 5 value inside the last row according to the rows you want retain before the first non-NA `numEggs`

```
example %>%
      mutate_at(vars(numEggs, numNestlings), na_if, 'unknown') %>%
      select(boxID, date, numEggs, visitType) %>%
      group_by(boxID) %>%
      slice((min(which(!is.na(numEggs)))-5):min(which(!is.na(numEggs))))

    # A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   boxID [1]
  boxID date       numEggs visitType
  <chr> <date>     <chr>   <chr>    
1 CA10  2018-03-26 NA      Image    
2 CA10  2018-03-27 NA      Image    
3 CA10  2018-03-27 NA      Image    
4 CA10  2018-03-27 NA      Image    
5 CA10  2018-03-28 NA      Image    
6 CA10  2018-03-28 1       Image
```